# How much does a group have to look reductive for it to be reductive?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$.  If $G$ is reductive, then there is a very nice structure of the Lie algebra of $G$ as a direct sum of the Lie algebra of a maximal torus and of one dimensional "root spaces," which come in pairs.  I was wondering if anything could be said about a converse.

Specifically, suppose $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$, and $Z_G(T) = T$, and assume the nonzero weights of $T$ under the rational representation $\textrm{Ad}: T \rightarrow \textrm{GL}(\mathfrak g)$ come in pairs $\alpha, - \alpha$, and each weight space $\mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ is one dimensional.  Can we conclude from here that $G$ is reductive?

The example I'm keeping in mind is $\textrm{Sp}_4$.  I have verified all these properties for $\textrm{Sp}_4$, but I have never actually gone to the trouble of showing that $\textrm{Sp}_4$ is reductive.  I was wondering whether what I have done so far is actually enough.  Or, are there a couple of other innocuous things to check in order to conclude $R_u(G) = 1$?